# get value from child component Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, authentication, jwt, vuejs3

This is my LoggedUser component which return the name of the logged user and its scope. the name will be displayed in the side bar and the scope will be used to display countries whom under the user's scope

```
<template>
{{ message }}
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
  export default {
    name: "LoggedUser",
    setup() {
        const message = ref('You are not logged in!');
        const scope = ref ('');
        onMounted(async () => {
            let token = '??';
            const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44391/api/Auth/User', {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
            token },
                credentials: 'include'
            });
            const content = await response.json();
            message.value = `Hi ${content.name}`;
            scope.value = `${content.scope}`;
        });

        return {
            message,
            scope
        }
    }
}
```

{{message}}is used in the sideBar component but i need scope in my Home.vue to use it in a test.
Here is my Home.vue component

```
 <template>
 <div class="container w-75" v-show="showGrid">
    <search-bar v-show="searchbar"></search-bar>
    <div class="row" style="width:900px; height:900px; padding-left:200px">
        <div class="col-md-4" v-for="country of countries" v-bind:key="country">
            <div class="card p-3" style="cursor:pointer">
                <router-link :to="{ path: '/FetchData', query: { query: country.countryName }}">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-2"><span>{{country.countryId}}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <h6 style="text-align:left">{{country.countryName}}</h6>
                </router-link>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between install mt-3">
                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><span v-if="!countries"><img src="../assets/loader.gif" /></span><br />
</div>
```

this is the vue part. I want to test user scope == country scope

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar.vue'
import SideBar from './SideBar.vue'
import LoggedUser from './LoggedUser.vue'

import swal from 'sweetalert';
import '@trevoreyre/autocomplete-vue/dist/style.css'
export default {
    name: "Home",
    components: {
        SearchBar,
        SideBar,
        LoggedUser
    },
    data() {
        return {
            countries: [],             
            showGrid: true,
            
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getCountries() {
            let country = this.$route.query.query
            if (!country) {
                axios.get("https://localhost:44391/api/Pho/GetCountries")
                    .then(res => this.countries = res.data)
            } else {
                axios.get("https://localhost:44391/api/Pho/GetCountries?country=" + this.$route.query.query)
                    .then(res => this.countries = res.data);
                this.searchbar = false;
                
            }
            
        },
```

I need to get scope value in Home.vue from LoggedUser.vue. How could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple options, one to put the api call to home, second option would be to use composition api and share a common state between these components and the third option would be to use a store management tool such as pinia or vuex.

Composition api would probably be the simplest solution. You basically just need to set a variable outside of the function that will be used in setup, short code example:

```js
const cart = ref({})

function useCart () {
  // super complicated cart logic
  return {
    cart: computed(() => cart.value)
  }
}
```

you still need to adjust this snippet to your needs it was just to show you a way

you can watch this talk by Vanessa Otto to hear more about how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgtQ9t74mhw